# Using Generics in C# to compare conditionally

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

In my scenario, I have two types of objects. A **plan** and a **tier**. Each one shares certain values, while the tier has 3 additional values (Rate, Min, and Max).

I would like to make a generic method to conditionally evaluate whether or not the new object can be written to the database, based on the following conditions:

Creation:

1. A tier: `((o1.Rate!=o2.Rate) || ((o1.Start!=o2.Start) && (o1.End!=o2.End))) && (MinVal && MaxVal)`
2. A tier or plan: `(o1.Name!=o2.Name)`
3. A tier or plan: Only one can have `(Active == true)`, the rest must be false.

Is it possible to create a generic method for something like this? If so, are there any examples of something like this? Or does anyone have suggestions?

thanks!

**MORE:**
So I have a list of objects, and I need to compare a newly created one with each other object in the database before I actually write it to the database.

Comment: Doesn't seem like a great fit, unless I'm missing something fundamentally simple in your question.

Comment: Do you want to make a method to *compare* two of these objects, or to *create* two of these objects? I really don't understand what you're trying to achieve here...

Comment: This sounds like an interesting question but I (and probably others) find it hard to discern what you're asking and your examples are hard to follow. Could add a sample of what you want your client code to look like?

Comment: I will be comparing an object that has ALREADY been created, with an object I WANT to create.

Comment: how can you compare something that exists with something that doesn't?

Comment: I create a temporary object, but I don't write it to the database until all conditions have been accepted.

Comment: I explained it further in the post, does that help?

Comment: it really is not clear what you want to achieve and where you have the objects to compare to - if you want to make sure there are no duplicates you need to know all existing object instances for comparison... this might work in a signle-threaded design... but if you plan on this in a multi-threaded scenario then you will have lots of contention and/or performance issues... which can be solved (complicated)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for this to work, the generic method (or type) would need a constraint that allowed it to understand all of the individual properties you have listed (`Rate`, `Date`, `MinVal`, `MaxValue`, `Start`, and `End`).

If all of the types which you are worried about derive from the same base class or interface, you don't need generics - just build a method that takes two arguments of that base type.

If, however, they don't, again, generics will likely not be a good fit here - however, there is another option.  You could use `dynamic` to effectively use these properties using runtime binding.  Just realize that, if you pass an argument of a type without those properties, it will fail *at runtime*.

Comment: to add further, this is using the entity framework - the objects created are in form of TblPlan / TblTier, so it does not inherit from a base class.

Answer (score 1):

I am really not sure what the question is... but if all this is some sort of "pre-check" before it gets created in the database I usually resort to a stored procedure in the database which takes alle relevant params for creation and return a primary key or when it fails an error code... in case of success then load with the primary key the created object from database...

The database is usually very efficient on such comparisons - and if I ever need to run multiple instances of the program in parallel and/or create objects independently from different programs the database solution takes care of it...

**EDIT - as per comment/request:**
I usually work with Oracle so I don't have any SQL Server Stored procedure at hand... but these links should provide some insight:

- https://web.archive.org/web/20211020103538/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/tips/t100901-1.shtml
- http://www.developerfusion.com/samplechapter/91/stored-procedures/4/
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187004.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190778.aspx

Comment: so you're saying I could write a stored procedure for SQL server which communicates back with the user to let them know their values already exist?

Comment: basically yes - the stored procedure communicates back either the new primary key (=sucess in creating the object), an error code (=failed due to existence of the object) / optionally an existing primary key for the already existing "duplicate object"... your program then commuicated this anyway you want back to the user...

Comment: do you know of any example of something like this that I could work with? I don't really know too much about stored procedures.

Comment: I usually work with Oracle but see my EDIT above - the links should give you a good starting point for SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
// I'm making up the types here; modify to match your actual types
public interface IMyObject {
    public int Rate { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int MinVal { get; set; }
    public int MaxVal { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
}

public static class MyObjectFactory {
    public static T Create<T>(int rate, DateTime date, /* etc.. */) 
            where T : IMyObject, new() {

        if (/* tests */) {
            throw new MyObjectException("Constraint violated ...");
        }             

        T obj = new T();

        obj.Rate = rate;
        obj.Date = date;
        // etc ....

        return obj;
    }
}
```

And then you would use it like so:

```
public class SomeMyObject : IMyObject {
    // implementation omitted for brevity ...
}

// somewhere:
SomeMyObject obj = MyObjectFactory.Create<SomeMyObject>(rate, date, /* etc. */);
```

Is that what you're asking for?

Comment: Well, if you look at my edited post, you will see that I mentioned that while a plan and tier share only 4  values while the tier has 3 additional values.

Answer (score 0):

Your options are basically:

1. use a common inherited base object with those props
2. implement an interface with those props
3. use reflection to get the values and compare them if the objects are really unrelated or if you only know the compared field values at runtime.

Reed mentioned below dynamic objects - that may work I'd have to trust his answer on that but includes the dynamic requirement though.